# Custom email template for a specific product category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am stuck in a situation where the requirement is to create a custom email template for a particular product category, so that when any user buy product from that category he/she get that customised order email. Please help if anyone have any idea about how this can be achieved. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly extend WC_Email class to define the email header, subject, email template for content

secondly, add custom email class to the default WooCommerce email classes using woocommerce_email_classes filter, with trigger that calls terms

```
if ( has_term( 'Your Cat', 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) )
```

lastly, Create an email template to be used to generate email content for your custom email.

this answer to this question involves a lot of code, far too much for SO so you may want to do some reading like.

https://cloudredux.com/adding-sending-custom-woocommerce-email/

Comment: Thanks @Brad, it was very helpful. Sorry for the late response

Comment: @PankajThakur no problem really glad this pointed you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Whatever plugin you're using for ecommerce, there should be an email hook available to customize the emails.

For example, WooCommerce provides 9 different hooks in its "new order" email. Here's a [visual reference](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-emails/).

Add a function that runs on the desired hook, and you can add conditional content. You'll have to find a way to identify "any product from a particular category" - pull order details, loop through the products, and if any of them is from that category, trigger your conditional content.

Further related reading: https://tommcfarlin.com/customizing-woocommerce-emails-hooks/

Comment: Thank you @webelaine, I got the reference from above answer and yours seems to be same thing.